# Customizing approval and workflow in JIRA service desk

Tags: jira

I'm trying to setup a JIRA service desk to accommodate the following flow:

- Staff (one of some like 20 people within the organization) can submit
  a request (status = submitted or initiated) via JIRA form
- Department Manager can approve or disapprove the request (status = approved)
- Service manager (1-2 people) can acknowledge the request (status = in progress)
- Service is done => service manager close the request (status = completed or cancelled)

Upon completion, the information from the original request will be pushed (hopefully automatically) to another system via API calls.

Do you know what would be the best way to setup the project template and approval and workflow? I'm a bit lost in the variety of templates that I could create in JIRA. I see some tutorials on Youtube but the options don't look the same. Apparently each template offers different functionalities and I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Jira Server or Jira Cloud (Jira Cloud will have a URL like .atlassian.net)

If Cloud..

Since you're creating service desk internal to your organization, go ahead with the 'General service desk' template option.

This won't create the Approval workflow for you. You'll have to create a new workflow, or edit one, and set up your statuses and approval.

Here are instructions for creating a workflow with approvals: https://support.atlassian.com/jira-service-desk-cloud/docs/set-up-an-approval-stage-for-a-request/

You'll have to configure one of the statuses in the workflow to request the Approval of a user or group.

If Server..

Create from the Basic Service Desk template. Same thing, you'll have to create a workflow for approvals and associate it to a request type. https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/configuring-jira-service-desk-approvals-938847527.html

[Approval Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp0cP.png)